# set subViews with different width horizontal in a superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, aspect-ratio, ios-autolayout

I wanted to create 6 subviews in a view, which have different width & same height. It should fit horizontal, all screen resolutions for iPad and iPhone.Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Use a UIStackView.

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional logic (i.e., which views to make smaller or not if the content does not fit), you can do this like this: if the views are ligned up from left to right and numbered 1 to 6

- defining the leftmost view (1) with a distance to left edge
- defining the rightmost view (6) with a distance to right edge
- defining the distances between the views (i.e. 1 to 2, 2 to 3 etc.)
- setting the horizontal "compression resistance priority" to differing values

You can set the same height individually, or just for one view and as equal height for the other views.

Comment: Yeah i tried to do this way. But it will ask me for width or x-position for all view.

Comment: You can adjust the horizontal "Content Compression Resistance Priority" so that they are all different.

Comment: Thank you. I have achieved it using Aspect ratio :)